# Hibernate: While using @Version getting StaleStateException

Tags: hibernate

**Explaination about the problem**

Please have a look at the code below, I am using @Version annonation and using two java classes : one to save the Student instance and another to update the same Student instance. I am providing the Id value from the instance itself. While updating for the first time, the value of the Student Name is getting updated and also the version is incremented by 1 but if it try to do it again changing the Student Name: I am getting the below exception. Please help !!!

```
**Student.java**

package com.emb.hib;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUD_ID")
    private int studId;

    @Column(name = "STUD_NAME")
    private String StudName;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer DEFAULT 0") 
    private long version;

    public Student(int studId, String studName) {
        super();
        this.studId = studId;
        StudName = studName;
    }

    public int getStudId() {
        return studId;
    }

    public void setStudId(int studId) {
        this.studId = studId;
    }

    public String getStudName() {
        return StudName;
    }

    public void setStudName(String studName) {
        StudName = studName;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}

**StudentRecSave.java**

package com.emb.hib;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class StudentRecSave {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
                .getMetadataBuilder().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
                .build();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Student rukmini = new Student(1, "Rukmini");

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(rukmini);
        tx.commit();

        session.close();
        System.out.println("Student record saved");
    }

}

**StudentRecUpdate.java**

package com.emb.hib;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class StudentRecUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
                .getMetadataBuilder().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
                .build();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Student rukmini = new Student(1, "Rukmini Iyer");

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(rukmini);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println("Student record updated");

    }

}



**hibernate.cfg.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> -->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root123</property> -->

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping package="com.emb.hib" />
        <mapping class="com.emb.hib.Student" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Console Output**

```
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.5.Final}
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/test]
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {}
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.emb.hib.Student (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.emb.hib.Person (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Hibernate: 
    /* get current state com.emb.hib.Student */ select
        student_.STUD_ID,
        student_.STUD_NAME as STUD_NAM2_1_,
        student_.VERSION as VERSION3_1_ 
    from
        STUDENTS student_ 
    where
        student_.STUD_ID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        com.emb.hib.Student */ update
            STUDENTS 
        set
            STUD_NAME=?,
            VERSION=? 
        where
            STUD_ID=? 
            and VERSION=?
Nov 16, 2016 12:42:13 PM org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$5 mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3070)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3329)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at com.emb.hib.StudentRecUpdate.main(StudentRecUpdate.java:27)
```

Comment: That's the whole point of the version field: you're trying to update a student, and the student you pass to saveOrUpdate() doesn't have the same version as the one in database, hence the exception. Why do you expect another result?

Comment: yes, i got your point. the transactions what I am doing, I am committing the changes. So, the value of version should be update for the latest. While doing for the second time, it should allow me to update the Student Name and implicitly increment version value by 1 right ?

Comment: You're creating a Student using new Student(). This sets the version in the created student to 0. But the version in database is 1. If you want to update a student, get it from the database, then update it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet. I was creating the Student instance and as per your suggestion, I did get the Student instance from the database and then updated the version with next value.